# Jio blocked raw.githubusercontent.com?

Tags: github

Did Jio block raw.githubusercontent.com? Because I cannot see images loaded from it on my GitHub unless I use a VPN which is quite annoying. Someone please confirm this and also any workarounds other than a VPN would be helpful.

I need this issue solved for my github overview readme, I am going to try to upload the images in google drive and try to fetch if from there using hyperlinks.

Comment: I don't know that we can answer that question. You should contact them and ask, and if they say yes, insist on having full, unfettered access to the Internet.  If they refuse, change providers.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, I was also facing this issue. But fortunately, I found a workaround for it! You can simply use the 1.1.1.1 DNS resolver provided by Cloudflare.

1. **What Does 1.1.1.1 Do?**
   1.1.1.1 is a public DNS resolver service provided by Cloudflare. It aims to improve both the speed and privacy of your internet connection. When you use 1.1.1.1, your DNS queries are resolved through Cloudflare's network, which is known for its reliability and speed. This can help in situations where your ISP's DNS servers might be slow or have issues resolving certain websites.
2. **How to Set It Up:**
   Setting up 1.1.1.1 is quite straightforward, and Cloudflare provides detailed instructions for different operating systems. Here's a link to set it up according to your operating system:
   [Setting Up 1.1.1.1 DNS](https://developers.cloudflare.com/1.1.1.1/setup/)

   Just follow the instructions for your specific OS, and you should be able to switch to using the 1.1.1.1 DNS resolver in no time.

By using 1.1.1.1 as your DNS resolver, you can potentially bypass any DNS-related issues or blocks that your ISP (Jio is this case) might have in place. It's a simple and effective way to improve your internet experience.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for this answer. It's working.

Comment: I added it in Jio Fiber router, and all the issues are resolved.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, Jio has a past of blocking domains before. In this case raw.githubusercontent.com URLs for no good reason.

As per the latest discussion, it seems that the ban has been lifted for some users but I still can't access it over JioFiber: https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/42655

If you use Linux, then adding the IP of raw GitHub URL to `/etc/hosts` has worked for me, as mentioned by this [GitHub user](https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/42655#discussioncomment-4943564) using the command below

```
sudo echo "185.199.108.133 raw.githubusercontent.com" >> /etc/hosts
```

Reboot the system after adding this in the DNS file in your respective operating system and it should work. Otherwise, reach out to JIO.